# jQuery - Event by scroll

Tags: jquery, events, scroll

The goal of my script is that when user scrolls down, my page should scroll to the next div. For this, the script distinguishes if the user scrolls up and down. After, when he scrolls, it should remove the class `active` of my first div and add to the next. Then it's scrolling to the new div with the class `active`. The problem is that it's working for the first scroll only, not the next.

My code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0;
    var $current = $("#container > .active");
    var next = $('.active').next();
    var prev = $('.active').prev();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop) { //scrolling down 
            $current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active'); 
            $.scrollTo(next, 1000);
        }
        else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop ) { //scrolling up
            $current.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
            $.scrollTo(prev, 1000);
        }

        tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    }); 
});
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

var lastScrollTop = 0;
var isDoingStuff = false;

```
$(document).scroll(function(event) {
    //abandon 
    if(isDoingStuff) { return; }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > lastScrollTop) {
        //console.log('down');
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next('div').addClass('active');
        isDoingStuff = true;
        $('html,body').animate( {scrollTop: $('.active').offset().top }, 1000, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {isDoingStuff = false;}, 100);
            console.log('off');
        });
    } else {
        //console.log('up');
    }
    lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the next and prev variables into the scroll function

```
$(window).load(function(){

var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0;



$(window).scroll(function(){

currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
//you need to assign the $current, next and prev here so they get the current elements (not the ones that were set at the beginning
var $current = $("#container > .active");    
var next = $('.active').next();
var prev = $('.active').prev();    


if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop )//scrolling down
{
$current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
$.scrollTo(next, 1000);
}
else if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop )//scrolling up

{
$current.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
$.scrollTo(prev, 1000);
}
tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
});
});
```

**UPDATED**
I added the $current var into the scroll function as well.

Comment: thanks, but when i do it, my scroll become crazy.
It's scrolling down and up alone.

Comment: Forgot to put the $current variable in there too. Try again.

Comment: Crazy = Jump up and down after the first scroll.
$.scrollTo is from the plugin jquery ScrollTo. It is using to scroll to my class active. You can see what's happen here : http://anthonykim.fr/stack/test5.html

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my fault forgot to add the $current var in there... I've updated the post

Comment: the class active do not be applied  just to the next div but att all